# Cannot create FULLTEXT index on temporary InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there a workaround for this error?

```
Cannot create FULLTEXT index on temporary InnoDB table
```

I'm creating a table like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA LIKE tableB
```

tableB is working and I don't want to touch it.

Comment: for what do you need the temporary table? fulltextindexes need a lot of resources and should only be used sparsely

Comment: I'm running into the same error.. I altered my main table ('tbl') with a FULLTEXT index so I could do MATCH and AGAINST boolean searches.. I need to create a temporary table using 'LIKE tbl' because I'm loading data into a temp table using 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' where I'm then doing an inner join with this 'temp table' and 'tbl'.